# Display rows values into columns grouping by a certain column

Tags: sql, excel

I have a certain set of data in MS-Excel as shown below -

```
unit    installment Amount  date
u1      m1          1500    11-Jan-14
u1      m2          1000    15-Apr-14
u1      m3          2500    17-Sep-14
u2      m1          2400    12-Feb-14
u2      m2          1800    14-Jun-14
u3      m1          8000    11-Jan-14
u3      m2          1600    15-Apr-14
u3      m3          4500    17-Sep-14
```

I need the output in MS-Excel in the following format -

```
Unit      m1    Date        m2     Date        m3   Date    
u1        1500  11-Jan-14   1000   15-Apr-14   2500 17-Sep-14       
u2        2400  12-Feb-14   1800   14-Jun-14                
u3        8000  11-Jan-14   1600   15-Apr-14   4500 17-Sep-14
```

This is something I need in the MS-excel version 2010. I am not sure if this is technically possible as such, I have searched for a possible solution but everywhere I end up going into transpose. But if you notice, this is actually not a transpose.

**NOTE**:- The set of installments (m1,m2,m3) is variable. However it can be assumed that all unique sets will be shown as column headers. If any unit does not have a milestone, it will be blank (eg:- for u2 above - m3 is blank).

Also if this solution is possible using SQL, even then I can work my way out to resolve this problem by getting to export the sql result in the excel. If the solution is possible in SQL, then please assume the above input data as a source table and output data as result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there is no duplicate pairs `Unit`/`Installment`, this transformation can be done in few click using [Pivot Table](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/create-a-pivottable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-HA102840046.aspx) (if there are duplicates, only agregate values (e.g. `max`) for `Amount` and `Date` would be displayed). Below is detailed explanation.

**Step1.**

Select your data, goto *`INSERT-->PivotTable`* and create new pivot table.

[image]

**Step2.**

Drag your column names (as in image below):

- `unit` to `ROWS` area.
- `installment` to `COLUMNS` area.
- `Amount` to `VALUES` area.
- `date` to `VALUES` area.

[image]

**Step3.**

Left mouse click on `Amount` field on `VALUES` area (could be named `Sum of Amount` or something like this) and click on *`Value Filed Settings...`*

[image]

**Step4.**

Change type of calculation to `Max` and name to `Amount_` (we can't use `Amount` name since we already have it in initial data, that's why I've added underscore `_` to name - you can change it to, say, space).

[image]

**Step5.**

Left mouse click on `Date` field on `VALUES` area (could be named `Count of Date` or something like this) and click on *`Value Filed Settings...`*

[image]

**Step6.**

Change type of calculation to `Max` and name to `Date_` (we can't use `Date` name since we already have it in initial data, that's why I've added underscore `_` to name - you can change it to, say, space).
Also for date field we should change *Number Format* (since it could be displayed as numbers instead as dates). So, click on *`Number Format`* button.

[image]

**Step7.**

Choose desired date format.

[image]

**Step8.**

If your table has Total columns/rows, you can disable them as in image below. *With active cell on pivot table* goto *`Design--> Grand Totals`* and select *`Off for Rows and Columns`*

[image]

**Result.**

Now your table is ready to use. If you don't want to use it like pivot table, just copy it's content somewhere else as plain data.

[image]

Comment: yes, there are not duplicates in Unit/Installment combination. I will try this and get back. Very elaborate and very useful answer. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I have tried this and is working fine as expected. When I had previously tried it, I had not done that MAX(Amount) and MAX(Date), thats where I missed out.